# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: UPDATE

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

There is something wrong with my update statement. I am trying to update an user from my database, I am sure this user is in my database, but I just can't update him. I think I have a fault with my column name because the error said:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: UPDATE
```

But I never asked for this column, `nnn` isn't a column at all in my scheme. Here is the statement

```
public void changeprofiel(String id, Profiel p){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();


   /* ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2_PROFIELEN, p.getUsername());
    contentValues.put(COL_3_PROFIELEN, p.getFirstname());
    contentValues.put(COL_4_PROFIELEN, p.getEmail());
    contentValues.put(COL_5_PROFIELEN, p.getPassword());*/

    // de insert methode geeft -1 terug als het niet gelukt is en de row value als het wel gelukt is

    System.out.println(getProfielWid(id).getId());
//    db.update(TABLE_NAME_PROFIELEN, contentValues,COL_1_PROFIELEN ="'" + id +"'",null);


    db.execSQL("UPDATE "+ TABLE_NAME_PROFIELEN + " SET "+COL_2_PROFIELEN+" = "+p.getUsername()+", " +COL_3_PROFIELEN+" = "+p.getFirstname()+", "+COL_4_PROFIELEN+" = "+p.getEmail()+", "+COL_5_PROFIELEN+" = "+p.getPassword()+
            " WHERE " + COL_1_PROFIELEN + "=" + id + "");

}
```

I also tried this way for the where closule:

```
" WHERE " + COL_1_PROFIELEN + "='" + id + "'");
```

But they give me both this error:

```
I/System.out: nnnnnn
E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such column: nnn
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.cedri.bcv, PID: 13908
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: nnn (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE profielen SET username = nnn, firstname = nnn, email = nnn, password = xxx WHERE profile_id=nnnnnn
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1677)
      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1608)
      at com.example.cedri.bcv.DB.DatabaseHelper.changeprofiel(DatabaseHelper.java:82)
      at com.example.cedri.bcv.Activities.MainActivity.savechanges(MainActivity.java:94)
      at com.example.cedri.bcv.Fragments.AccountFragment$1.onClick(AccountFragment.java:86)
      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6121)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:889)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:779)
```

Do I need to set every value between single quotes?

Comment: Learn to use parameters.  Don't dump random strings into query strings.  You are likely to get syntax errors (as well as making the code susceptible to SQL injection).

Comment: yes if you use rawquery then every text/string type value need to be in single quote, but u can adopt @Gordon suggested method here u get an idea https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: thanks i worked with the single quotes!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your values with single quotes (`''`) if the column's type is `text`.

Your query should look like this:

```
UPDATE profielen SET username = 'nnn', firstname = 'nnn', email = 'nnn', password = 'xxx' 
WHERE profile_id='nnnnnn'
```